# A $d$-form on ${\mathbb R}^n$ that vanishes on $\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}$ general points, vanishes identically

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, projective-geometry

I'm looking for a reference for the fact that a $d$-form on ${\mathbb R}^n$ that vanishes on $p_1,..,p_{\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}}$ general points, vanishes identically. 
A specific construction of a set of points is also welcomed. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's not true even for $n=1$!

Comment: To clarify, for $n=1$ and for any $d$ the only form is $\alpha x^d$. Of course if it vanishes for $p_1\ne 0$  then $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Ah, well, in the case the polynomial is homogeneous, I guess you can just use the fact that the points impose independent conditions - this can be proved by induction and an exact sequence on projective space.

Answer (score 2):

See [Sauer and Xu, "On multivariate Lagrange interpolation"](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1995-64-211/S0025-5718-1995-1297477-5/S0025-5718-1995-1297477-5.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps I missed it but I could not find a direct proposition for the above fact in the text. Could you cite the proposition number you refer to ?

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of the [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of homogeneous polynomials $R_d(\mathbb R^n)$ is indeed $\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}$.

But for $n>1$ your claim does not hold for **all** layouts of the points. (It's a consequence of Mairhuber–Curtis theorem proving that there are no Haar spaces in $n>1$).

For example, take a linear $d=1$ polynomial $ax+by\in R_1$ on $\mathbb R^2$. The graph of $p=ax+by$, a plane, intersects the $xy$-plane along the line $ax+by=0$, so if the both ($\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}=2$) of our sample points are on the intersection line then $p=0$, but not necessarily $p\equiv0$. For the latter we need to take the second point to be not collinear with the first and the origin. Demanding that $p=0$ on these two points (and the origin) then leads to $p\equiv0$. Such arrangements of points are called *unisolvent*, at least in the field of approximation theory and multivariate polynomial interpolation. See, for example, the Definition 2.6 in Wendland's "Scattered data approximation". It basically says

**Definition.** Points are called
$\Pi$-unisolvent if the zero polynomial is the only polynomial from $\Pi$ that vanishes
on all of them.

Comment: user612313 - thanks for your answer. What is is meant by general points is almost all (in the measure sense).